# How to check the size of a shared folder on Google Drive before downloading

Tags: google-drive

Suppose, someone shared a folder with me on Google Drive. I want to know the size of that folder. How can I check that without downloading the folder?

I tried to find any relevant options but couldn't get any.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The best way is probably to either use Drive File Stream (and see the properties of the folder in the file manager before downloading it), or perhaps the folder size is visible in the Backup and Sync Preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no options provided for checking folder sizes whether they are shared or not. There is a whole [thread](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/3970069?hl=en) at Google Support since 2019 asking how to check (normal) folder size. However, Google has not yet implemented the feature.